# Remove NFC confirmation popup in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am working on my NFC project and came across problem while launching an app. it always ask about confirmation.Is there any way to remove the confirmation popup while tapping NFC tags with windows phone 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to remove this confirmation popup. It has been put there for security reasons (to avoid launching an app from a malicious NFC tag without the user consent), and is only disabled on some OEM NFC tags (like the ones included in Nokia's wireless chargers).

Comment: I agreed with you.But i saw videos on Youtube using NFC tag with Lumia for movie and train tickets.That applications not prompting and confirmation popup.

Comment: Yes. We're talking about two different things: launching an application with a NFC tag requires confirmation. Reading a NFC tag **from** your application doesn't require a confirmation, but it means that the user had first to launch the application

Comment: Yes. But reading every time from app require launching an app confirmation as well.Problem is there to remove launching confirmation every time. Any work around to disable confirmation?

Comment: Actually some of Nokia's OEM accessories still pop-up a confirmation, e.g. CR-200 wireless car charger (UK version, tested Nov-2013).

Comment: This is really annoying.